# Http Load Testing

Tags: scala, akka, microservices, akka-http

I am trying to create a simple microservice that can handle 1 million requests at a time. But I am getting connection reset error on my client side. Correct me in case I am making any mistake.

**Server Code**
1. **Listener** :

```
  object Collection {
  case class calculate(values:Double)
 }

 object EngineController{

 import Collection._


def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
try {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()
  implicit val executionContext = system.dispatcher
val requestHandler = system.actorOf(RoundRobinPool(3).props(RequestHandler.props), "round-robin-pool")
  val route: Route = {
    implicit val timeout = Timeout(100.seconds)
    path("aggregate") {
      log.info("REQUEST RECEIVED")
      post {
        entity(as[String]) { values =>
          onSuccess(requestHandler ? calculate(values)) {
            case result: Double =>
              log.info("Response Sent -" + result)
              complete(s"${result}")

          }
        }
      }
    } 
  }
  val routeBinding :Future[ServerBinding] = Http().bindAndHandle(route, "localhost", 8080)
  log.info("Connection Established! Waiting for Request")
  routeBinding.failed.foreach { ex =>
    log.error(ex, "Failed to bind to {}:{}!", host, port)
  }
  StdIn.readLine()

  routeBinding.flatMap(_.unbind())
  system.terminate()

}

catch {
  case ex: Exception =>
    log.error(ex, ex)
}
}
}
```

2. RequestHandler: This actor return max of the number.

   ```
   object RequestHandler extends App {
   def props: Props = {
   Props(classOf[RequestHandler])
     }

   class RequestHandler extends Actor {
   var doubleArray: Array[Double] = Array.empty
   val system1 = ActorSystem("system2")
   var routees: List[ActorRef] = _
   override def preStart() = {
   routees = List.fill(5)(
   context.actorOf(AggregateCalculator.props)
   )
   }
   val aggregateActor = system1.actorOf(AggregateCalculator.props.withRouter(RandomPool(100)), "ag")

    //CONVERT STRING TO ARRAY
    def stringToArray(values: String): Array[Double] = {
    return values.split(",").map(x => x.toDouble)
    }

    override def receive: Receive = {
    case calculate(values) =>
    doubleArray = stringToArray(values)
    sender() ! doubleArray.max
      }
     }
    }
   ```

**Client Code** :

```
 package Test
 import scalaj.http.{Http, HttpResponse}
 import org.apache.log4j.Logger


 //libraryDependencies += "org.scalaj" % "scalaj-http_2.11" % "2.3.0"
 object RequestSender1 {
val log = Logger.getLogger(getClass.getName)
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
try {
  val str = "22.78, -1.23, 50, 60, 3, 32, 11, 54, 72, 78, 99, 70, 19, 47, 90, 81, 50, 69, 69, 72, 83, 14.7, 8, 41, 65, 73, 48, 63, 47, 17, 55, 39, 50, 87, 76, 8, 67, 51, 55, 94, 75, 14, 91, 35, 87, 36, 42, 74, 70, 81, 18, 14, 50, 22, 16, 55, 71, 17, 39, 44, 58, 61, 16, 4, 74, 61, 37, 31, 62, 36, 53, 30, 82, 72, 89, 96, 28, 36, 77, 89, 30, 2, 31, 79, 50, 34, 81, 39, 91, 85, 94, 25, 68, 98, 46, 42,14,14"
  var result: HttpResponse[String] = null
  var counter = 0
  for (i <- 1 to 300) {

    for (i <- 1 to 13000) {
      val thread = new Thread {
        override def run {
          while (counter < 1000024) {
            try {
              counter += 1
              result = scalaj.http.Http("http://localhost:8080/aggregate").postData(str).timeout(1200000, 120000000) //192.168.0.157:8089
                .header("Content-Type", "text/plain").asString
              println("Thread Count----" + java.lang.Thread.activeCount())
              j += 1
              println(result.body + "   " + j)
            } catch {
              case ex:Exception =>
                log.error(ex)
            }
          }
        }
      }
      thread.start
      // slow the loop down a bit
    }
    println("Sent request with --" + i)
    Thread.sleep(1)
    // slow the loop down a bit
 }
}
catch {
  case ex:Exception =>
    println("Exception"+">>>>>>>>>>")
}
```

}
}

**Error 1** :

```
09:58:07 ERROR [Thread-12803] - Test.RequestSender1$.run 32 - java.net.BindException: Address already in use: connect
```

**Error 2** :

```
Thread-12418" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
```

**Sorry for Bad Allignment**

Answer (score 0):

I think this has nothing to do with Scala or HTTP. It is a limitation of the TCP protocol.

Unfortunately you just can't create 1 million outbound TCP connections from a single machine. TCP connection is specified by two pairs (IP address, port) for client and server. The server might have all connections coming to the same port and distinguish them by the client information. But for any typical TCP/IP implementation each outbound connection will have its own unique TCP port assigned to it (and even if you roll out some custom implementation you still can't have two outgoing connections to the same server/port from the same client/port because they will be indistinguishable). [TCP port](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol#TCP_ports) is actually just a 16-bit number. It means there are only about 65k ports altogether which is obviously much less than 1 million you want. So to make 1 million connections you will require many machines (or at least virtual machines) running the test at the same time.

Comment: I am getting the error after sending 20k requests (sometimes after 8k requests also) and my server is running on a high capacity machine only.

Comment: @BishnuShankarPandey, capacity doesn't matter in the respect. If number of requests before error differs significantly - my diagnosis is probably wrong. To make sure could you convert you `counter` to a `@volatile` field or `AtomicInt`? AFAIU typically [range of ports given to clients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers#Dynamic,_private_or_ephemeral_ports) is about 2^14 i.e. only 16k. Given that you have 13k threads and there might be some delays in actually releasing the ports, 20k requests sounds as a reasonable number to hit the limit. 8k request is too small.

Comment: but for 8k requests also it is giving the error. Suggest me what to do at this point to make my microservice  to accept 1 million requests

Comment: @Prog_G, first I suggest to ensure that it is only 8k. You current `counter` is not thread-safe i.e. it might show much less value that you actually made requests. Thus I suggested either using `@volatile` or `AtomicInt`. **_If_** my diagnosis is correct, I think you should try setting up  several virtual machines and running tests in parallel from them. Also note that my diagnosis says you can't do testing this way. It says nothing about the server. But I suspect that the server couldn't handle 1M incoming connections without serious tuning of the OS kernel anyway.

Comment: Thank you. After declaring counter as @volatile I am not getting that error. Can you explain how it fixed it?

Comment: @Prog_G, it only makes me believe that I made the correct diagnosis in the first place. By using `@volatile` you enforce some synchronization between threads (i.e. slow them down a bit) and this probably give infrastructure (JVM, OS) enough time to actually close sockets (TCP connections) before your threads ask for new exceeding the limit. You might try to get the old (failing) behavior by creating an array of int counters for each thread and summing the array after the first failure to get the actual total request count

Comment: Now at this point what I should do to check for more number parallel requests?

Comment: @Prog_G, sorry I don't think I understand your question. Your 1 million goal is quite ambitious. I don't think you can achieve it using just code. You will need some OS administration level tricks. You may start with [this article](https://mrotaru.wordpress.com/2013/10/10/scaling-to-12-million-concurrent-connections-how-migratorydata-did-it/) for some suggestions.